# Is it safe to carry luxury luggage?

Tags: luggage, public-transport, georgia-country, luxury

Are luxury bags and clothing designed to be safely checked in luggage or carried around if travelling on a budget? Is it advisable to use such items in regular transportation, or are they more suitable for luxury vehicles or yachts? I'm planning a trip to Georgia and Armenia and want to bring belongings I am accustomed with, but I'm unsure about the practicality since no one really does that and since I don't really know where I will be going.

I have many things from Kenzo brand, which I believe is a travel brand/line, but I am not sure how people in other countries react and whеter it was actually designed for travel or to stay in my closet.

Comment: What items?  Luxury means different things to different people, and quality probably varies between manufacturers (and many possibly label their items as luxury even when they're the same as non-luxury items)

Comment: Yes, I think I have many items from Kenzo, I think thus line is discontinued, so it is not really inspirational any more

Comment: Are those photos your own? If not, you should credit the owner of the rights and have permission of the people. It is better not to post photos with people in them. I have removed the unneeded ones.

Comment: What do you mean by the word "safe" ?

Comment: I actually mean, if benefits outweigh risks

Comment: @Willeke indeed these pictures belong to to brand Kenzo, I think I have it mentioned.

Comment: If they belong to the brand you have no rights to repost them.

Comment: @Willeke such a lay point of view

Comment: @Willeke please stop deleting pictures#2 and 3, believe me, they are by no means in any different category than the picture #1

Comment: They are the same categorie, violation of copyright. So now all go. You can post a photo you made yourself but remember the copyright of the brand on their design.

Answer (score 9):

I typically avoid bringing expensive stuff when I travel. It certainly can be done but it will often require extra caution & attention and can cause extra stress, which takes away from the travel experience. I prefer things that are a practical, don't attract undue attention and that I won't miss too much if they are lost, misplaced or damaged. It's just more fun and relaxing to travel this way.

In general flaunting wealth while travelling is not a great idea, as it attracts the wrong type of attention. You'll make yourself an attractive target for pickpockets, hustlers and tip hunters. How much of those you encounter will depend a lot on WHERE you are going and what you are planning to do. This being said, in my experience the main cause of loss is simply losing stuff and normal wear and tear. Keep in mind that wear and tear is significantly harsher on the road than it is at home. Some amount of loss and breakage is a given when travelling (frequently) and this is much less of a bother if your stuff isn't overly expensive.

Another thing to consider is insurance, etc. For example, the Montreal Convention limits the compensation for lost/damaged airline luggage to about USD 1,700 per passenger and many transportation and service providers have similar limitations. If your stuff significantly exceeds these limits, you probably should pony up for extra insurance, which can be expensive (and you carefully need to read the fine print).

So yes, you can travel with luxury goods but it will require location specific measures to keep it safe and, in my opinion, is less fun than travelling with crummy stuff (as I do).

Comment: I actually think it would be around 1700 per bag: the bag was about 200, then t-shirts 100, shorts 200 etc. The bag also has exact dimensions for hand luggage.

Comment: I believe it’s $1700 per passenger, not per bag.

Comment: @jcaron: good catch, I'll fix that

Comment: Montreal Convention limits the liability, but it can be more, not less https://www.nerdwallet.com/article/travel/delayed-baggage-compensation-broken-down-by-airline#what-baggage-delay-compensation-am-i-entitled-to

Comment: @troyan: this $1700 per passenger. That's ALL your stuff that you checked.

Comment: @Hilmar airlines can provide more if they want (usually for an extra fee of course).